# Extend a partial with excludes ignores the excluded properties

Tags: typescript

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding how `Exclude` works but I have the following issue:

```
export interface Base {
    page: number;
    count: number;
}

export interface Sub extends Partial<Exclude<Base, 'count'>> { // error
    count?: 'nonzero'|'zero';
}
```

The interface `Sub` is causing an error saying `Sub` incorrectly extends interface `Partial<Base>` however this is not what I was expecting. I was expecting that `Sub` extends `Partial<{ page: number }>` which is what I thought was the type of `Exclude<Base, 'count'>` however it does not seem to be the case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20interface%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20page%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Sub%20extends%20Partial%3CExclude%3CBase%2C%20'count'%3E%3E%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3F%3A%20'nonzero'%7C'zero'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Sub2%20extends%20Partial%3CPick%3CBase%2C%20'page'%3E%3E%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0A%20%20%20%20count%3F%3A%20'nonzero'%7C'zero'%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

`Exclude` removed a type from a union. So for example `Exclude<'a' | 'b', 'b'>` will be `a`. It does not remove properties from a type.

Generally the type that removed properties from another type is called `Omit`. `Omit` will be included in 3.5, but is simple to define in terms of `Pick` and `Exclude` (below is actually the 3.5 definition of `Omit`):

```
type Omit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
export interface Base {
    page: number;
    count: number;
}

export interface Sub extends Partial<Omit<Base, 'count'>> { // ok
    count?: 'nonzero'|'zero';
}
```